# Grep command for getting logs using adb for a specific package

Tags: android-emulator, adb

Grep command for obtaining a logs for specific package. I tried with multiple commands from google none of it was working. Is there any presteps which I need to be performing before running this. I specifically need to see the logs for packages for android?

Comment: "I tried with multiple commands from google none of it was working" Please edit your question and include the commands that don't work. And what do you mean by "package", are you referring to the packageName of an app? So do you want to view logcat of a specific app?

Answer (score 0):

`adb` provides filters so you most probably won't need `grep`, use

```
adb logcat MyApp:D
```

BTW: as @Robert commented, you should have provided your efforts, but as they probably use `grep` I'm showing the proper solution here but keep that in mind